# Colorbox previous and next buttons not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have been working on a e-commerce site to show the images of a product however i am having some trouble.

I am using colorbox to show the image in a popup window my code for that is:

```
jQuery("a.largeImgPop").colorbox({opacity:0.4, rel:'largeImgPop', photo:true});
```

With my links looking like this:

```
<a class="largeImgPop" href="/img1.jpg">test1</a>
<a class="largeImgPop" href="/img2.jpg">test2</a>
<a class="largeImgPop" href="/img3.jpg">test3</a>
```

When i click on either test1, test2 or test3 it is showing the correct image however it does not show the previous and next button to navigate between the three. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i wasnt seeing the previous and next buttons was because of the z-index. The buttons were hidden behind the image that was being shown within colorbox. To fix this i increased the z-index of the buttons within the css of colorbox and then repositioned them to where I wanted them

To learn more about z-index click below:

[Click Here for z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have missed one of these 2 things.

Not copied the colorbox images into your project

Or

Copied them into your project but forgotten to update the CSS file to point the images to the right location.